# Updating SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

I'm trying to update the SQL Server Express version to 2012 or 2014, but after I run the installers and open SQL Server manager it shows:

PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server 9.0.1399 - username) and if I'm correct that's 2005.

I've tried both upgrading and standalone installs with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: When you install, what name do you give to your instance?  PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS is the 2005 instance.  If you don't give any name, that means it's a default instance.  Try to access it with just PCNAME

Comment: I don't remember seeing an option to name the instance, but I've only tried a standalone install once. Maybe I'll try that again. I tried accessing it with just PCNAME and it said it could not connect.

Comment: In Windows, go to Services, look for SQL Server services.  It will list all the SQL Server instance running in your system.

Comment: Thanks @Eric that helps out. I think something is wrong with the machine I'm installing it on as I've gotten it working on a different machine.